# What does "return obj(value); return?

Tags: c++, return

What does `return obj(value);`return? Returns it the newly constructed object or a copy of it?

The reason why I am asking:
Is

```
return obj(value);
```

more efficient than

```
temp = obj(value); 
return temp;
```

?

Follow-up: If so, is it really a difference, or do compilers optimize this away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return statement *always* returns a *copy* of the argument object with one exception: when the function returns a reference, the reference might be attached to the argument of `return` directly, in which case no copy is made, of course.

For this reason, from the pedantic point of view in your case there's no way to say what happens, since we don't know the signature of the function in which your `return` is used. Does it return a reference or not?

If we assume that the function returns a non-reference type (and that is probably what you implied), then, again, a copy is returned in both cases. In the second case you also yourself make an extra copy in `temp` object. So, from the abstract point of view, the second variant makes one extra copy and therefore is "slower". However, C++ language allows rather far-reaching optimizations in cases like that. Read about RVO (return value optimization) and NRVO (named return value optimization). Because of these optimizations it is actually possible that both variants will produce the same code and, obviously, will be equally efficient.

In the end it boils down to the code your specific compiler will be able to generate. If you want to know which is faster either time it with your specific compiler and with your specific compiler settings. Or inspect the generated machine code.

Comment: This is way wrong.  There is no extra copy.  Both create the same amount of objects when you leave optimizations out of the picture.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: Absolutely incorrect. The first variant creates temporary `obj(temp)` and an implicit "return buffer" temporary. The second variant creates temporary `obj(temp)`, named object `temp` and an implicit "return buffer" temporary. I.e. the second variant creates an extra object: `temp`. Any deviations from that behavior are *optimizations*.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie- Are you sure about that?  The second version makes a copy of the return value, stores it in temp, then makes another copy when returning it.  Many compilers will elide the copy using the RVO or NRVO, but there's no guarantee that they actually will.

Comment: @template - yeah, I'm sure.  The OP obviously forgot to put `obj` before `temp = ...`.  This is initialization syntax and doesn't create any extra copies.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie- I need to check the spec, but my understanding was that the initialization syntax technically does make a copy but says that compilers can elide it if they choose.  I'll get back to you after I look it up.  But that is a good point.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: Obviously? No. There's no `obj` before `temp` in the original post, so initialization is out of the question for now.

Comment: @templatetypedef: If that were an *initialization* (as in `obj temp = obj(value);`), then indeed there woudn't be an extra copy there, because copy-initialization with the same type used on LHS and RHS is actually a direct-initialization (i.e. it would be equivalent to `obj temp(value);`)

Comment: @template - even if you're right, that isn't an optimization it's just implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @AndreyT - by that argument there's no `temp` either and the code doesn't compile so the question is moot.  The OP's post absolutely must be interpreted based on what they seem most clearly to be asking.  Requiring the least amount of additions, the question must be "Does giving a return value a name cause more copies?"  It does not.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: Er... Well, I'd say that you go a little to far with that. One can also argue that a return statement without an enclosing function will not compile either. Yet, I believe that it is perfectly reasonable to assume that we are talking about a function context. Assuming that `temp` is declared somewhere is not that much different. Although from the pedantic point of view we need to know the exact type of `temp` and how it is declared (could be a static object).

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: Also, "giving the return value a name" might not create more copies. But just "giving the return value a name" is quite a specific situation. You have to be quite careful to achieve exactly that ("giving the return value a name") instead of actually creating an extra copy.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie- You are absolutely right - that is direct initialization and it's equivalent to a direct call to the copy constructor.  I stand corrected.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't more efficient. It return a new created value as a copy. But in both cases it's possible that the compiler optimize the return value.

Answer (score 0):

*What does return obj(value);return?*

An obj.

*Returns it the newly constructed object or a copy of it?*

Depends on the compiler.

*more efficient than*

No.

However, once we add optimizations to the compiler the story can change.  NRVO and RVO are different optimizations.  The compiler can apply one and not the other.